# params value undefined in Protracor

Tags: javascript, random, parameters, protractor, config

I having random failures in Protractor, because of undefined value. In conf file I have the following:

```
homeData: {
            numericString: '123456789',
            balanceRandomNumbers: parseInt(Math.random()*100000)
        },
```

In the spec file I have the following:

```
    var randomNumbers = browser.params.homeData.balanceRandomNumbers;
    var numberKeys = element(by.id("shiftStartingBalanceModal")).element(by.css(".virtualKeyboardContainer")).element(by.name("default"));

    describe(...
        it(...
            // split numbers and store into variable
            splitedRandomNumbers = randomNumbers.toString().split("");

            // print out splited variable value in console
            console.log("\nBalance value: " + splitedRandomNumbers);

            // waiting for onscreen keyboard "1" key to be visible
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(numberKeys.element(by.buttonText("1"))),10000);

            // selecting balance value
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                numberKeys.element(by.buttonText(splitedRandomNumbers[i])).click();
                browser.sleep(100);
            };
...
```

Now when I run this spec, I randomly get error stating that the **splitedRandomNumbers** is undefined. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're stopping your loop at 5, I'm going to go ahead and guess splitedRandomNumbers does not have a length of 5, so your last few loops are undefined.  Why don't you use `splitedRandomNumbers.length` as the loop condition?

Comment: I don't know why I did it like that as I use .lenght in other cases. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Was that the issue though or is there still a problem?

Comment: This was the issue as I don't get any undefined errors anymore. Thanks again!